# Azure Lighthouse onboarding customers not in customers list

Tags: azure

Days ago I onboarded a customer using Service Principal with an ARM template in our blob storage, then the client went to this URL:

`https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/{Blob Url}`, accepted us as their resource manager, and we could make connections and go-to resources but via PowerShell, why it doesn't show to us in our Azure Lighthouse Customers page?

I can work with the resources, make deployments, and such but doesn't show in the list, I want to know if it is because we need to be gold competency or an expert MSP because we don't want to make a public offer in the market, we just want to manage certain customers.

Answer (score 0):

It should be displayed there.  No special conditions are required such as the ones you've mentioned.  Are you definitely signed in to your own partner/MSP tenant with an account that has delegated access to the customers?  Does anything show up under delegations within the Azure Lighthouse section?

If you have access to the customer tenant, does your company show up under Service Providers within Azure Lighthouse on the Azure portal?

Comment: Note - this should really be a comment, not an answer, as you're asking for additional clarification (and there's really no answer here...)

Comment: Yes I got another account from the tenant, and they see us as their service provider and see delegations and all, but we don't see the client in the list.

Comment: Strange. It usually appears after a few minutes maybe after logging out and back in again.  Are you definitely signed in to the Azure portal with an account with at least delegated Reader access to the customer subscription?  There are some troubleshooting steps here that you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lighthouse/how-to/onboard-customer#troubleshooting

Comment: Yes I am, I submitted a ticket to Microsoft and told me that my USER has to be also included in the ARM template with Read built-in role, besides the service principal as Contributor, will let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Case closed, the Service Principal itself doesn't have the privileges on the service provider's tenant to make your user a reader. So the solution for this was:

1. Remove the offer in the customer tenant.
2. Add new authorization in the ARM template for a user/group with "Reader" built-in role id. (In our case, we decided to use an AD group because people in the organization is temporary)
3. Upload the new ARM template and re-onboarded the client.
4. After a couple of hours, the client's subscription showed in the subscription list in the section: Directories + subscriptions, checked it, and saw all the resources from the service provider's tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue.

The Azure Lighthouse->My customers list on the azure portal only shows subscriptions activated in the global directories and subscription filter.

Please go to the global directories and subscriptions filter (in the portal top navigation) and open the drop downs for directories and for subscriptions and check, if your customer subscription appears here.

If yes, select all entries in both drop downs.

After that go back to Azure Lighthouse->My customers
and check, if the customer subscription appears now.